# MySQL get n rows per key

Tags: mysql, pdo

Given a very simple table *bits*:

```
ID | bit_id | timestamp | percent | delta
```

where bitid is *varchar(255)* and timestamp is a *bigint*.

There are many, many rows with identical bit_id's. ID is primary and timestamp is not unique.

With the following SQL i get the rows for a specific set of bit_id's:

```
SELECT bits.bit_id, bits.timestamp, bits.percent 
FROM bits 
WHERE bits.bit_id IN ( '00e04c0353bc', '00e04c02c749' ) 
AND bits.timestamp>1480075040 
ORDER BY bits.timestamp DESC
```

What i want is only the 5 latest rows, **per bit_id** that match the WHERE-statement. So for each given bit_id in the subset, i want the 5 newest rows.

So simply adding LIMIT n won't do.

How? My MySQL-version does not work with LIMIT in sub-selects.

Comment: Have you tried using `GROUP BY bit_id` ?

Comment: What would you like to see if the five newest timestamps are the same for a given bit_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only two values, then the easiest way is `union all`:

```
(SELECT b.bit_id, b.timestamp, b.percent 
 FROM bits b
 WHERE b.bit_id = '00e04c0353bc'
       b.timestamp > 1480075040 
 ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 5
) UNION ALL
(SELECT b.bit_id, b.timestamp, b.percent 
 FROM bits b
 WHERE b.bit_id = '00e04c02c749'
       b.timestamp > 1480075040 
 ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 5
);
```

I'm not sure if the `WHERE` condition on `timestamp` is necessary.

If you wanted to do this for more `bit_id`s or all of them, then variables might be simpler:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             (@rn := if(@b = bit_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@b = bit_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from bits b cross join
           (select @b := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by b.bit_id, b.timestamp desc
     ) b
where rn <= 5;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! it' always for 1 to 5 bit_id's so, a simple loop does the trick.